# Positioning page numbers on a PDF produces asymmetrical results

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

The following LaTeX file, produces a 2 page blank PDF (thanks to egreg for the code).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
blank.pdf
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% or letterpaper or whatever
\def\loopnum{2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\count255=0 \loop\ifnum\count255<\loopnum \null\vfill\eject\advance\count255 1 \repeat
\end{document}
```

The following LaTeX file places page numbers on that PDF. However, the `\put` command does not move the page numbers symmetrically, even though the logic seems the same. Specifically, the `2` is much closer to the paper edge than the `1`. Without the `put` command they appear to be in the same relative positions. My question is why this is the case, and should I be using another positioning command? Perhaps the mirroring code is interacting badly with the positioning code?

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-30,30){\thepage}\end{picture}}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{blank.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are moving the number 30pt to the left on both even and odd pages so the positioning is inherently asymmetical. Perhaps you want to specify LE and RO separately and use 30 in one case and -30 in the other? (and probably `\llap` and `\rlap` the page numbers as well

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, in hindsight this was (another) stupid question. Shows how little multiple degrees and many years of schooling are really worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\put(30,30)` on even numbered pages and `\put(-30,30)` on odd numbered pages.

In the code below I used `showframe` to better show the positioning and `\Huge` for the page numbers so they are more visible.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(30,30){\makebox[0pt]{\Huge\thepage}}\end{picture}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-30,30){\makebox[0pt]{\Huge\thepage}}\end{picture}}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{blank.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]